# How to link comments to each post by id with Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, loops

I have created a Post and Comment application. I am trying to link the comments to the `id` of the post. I am trying to use PHP in a Blade template to do this. I get the error that the variable `post_id` does not exist. I want to use the `@if` and `@foreach` of Blade. The problem seems to be in the `@if` statement.

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="row">
        @foreach($posts as $post)
          <div class="col-md-12 post" id="post{{ $post->id }}">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h4>
                          {{ $post->title }}
                      </h4>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 post-header-line">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> by <a href="#">{{ $post->user->firstName }} {{ $post->user->lastName }}</a> | <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                      </span> {{ $post->created_at }} | <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><a href="#">
                          3 Comments</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row post-content">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                      <a href="#">
                          <img src="/images/random/postimg.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive postImg">
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-10">
                      <p>
                          {{ $post->post }}
                      </p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row add-comment">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="addComment" placeholder="Add your comment" class="form-control" v-model="comment">
                </div>
                <input id="addComment" type="submit" name="submitComment" value="Submit Comment" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="submitComment" data-id="{{ $post->id }}">

              </div>

              @if($post->comment->post_id == $post->id)
                @foreach($post->comment as $comment)

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-r">
                        <div class="card example-1 scrollbar-ripe-malinka">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 id="section1"><strong>By: {{ $comment->user->firstName }} {{ $comment->user->lastName }}</strong></h4>
                                <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                @endforeach
              @endif
          </div>
          @endforeach
      </div>
  </div>
```

Here is my PostController:

```
  public function index(){
      $posts = Post::with('comment', 'user')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
      return view('post.posts')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

Comment: what's your problem??

Comment: I get error of undefined variable in the `@if` statement for `post_id` and I'm not sure why.

Comment: check my answer, i have made answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@if` statement, remove it. `$post->comment` is a collection, that 's why your are not getting `post_id`. if you want to check, then check inside `foreach`.

```
            @foreach($post->comment as $comment)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mb-r">
                    <div class="card example-1 scrollbar-ripe-malinka">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 id="section1"><strong>By: {{ $comment->user->firstName }} {{ $comment->user->lastName }}</strong></h4>
                            <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Removing it places all the comments under the first post, not per post

Comment: @Horcrux I have edited my answer, check `@if` inside foreach

Comment: That did not work either. All comments still under the first post

Comment: show us your db schema, model class, relationship, and in your view, there is no need to add `@if` statement if you defined your relationship well

Comment: I have found the issue - I didn't check my database. It kept saving the `id` as the same one when adding a comment. Will have to look at getting the correct id of the post when adding it.

Comment: great work, one thing again, you could and you should remove if statement as it is of no use

Comment: I did thanks :) thanks for your help. Next time I should just check the database first.

Comment: if it solves your current problem, then make a vote, accept it. In future it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `post_id` to the `comments` table and use the relationship:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Then you'll be able to load related comments:

```
Post::with('comments', ....
```

And iterate over posts and their comments:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
        {{ $comment->content }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have the relationships set up. I have no problem with the foreach. The problem is in the `@if`

Comment: @Horcrux you don't need to use `@if` here at all if the relationship was defined correctly. Just iterate over posts and comment as I've shown.

Comment: Here is my relationships:
Post Model:
'public function comment(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }'

Comment Model:
`public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create relationship between Post model and Comment model (post table and comments table), your @if is useless. I recommend you to check your corresponding models.

Your code should be like this,
Post.php

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comments','commentable');
}
```

Comment.php

```
public function commentable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

in my app Comment model is shared by some other models also.

Eg :- User’s Questions also have comments. 
Find more details in [laravel:Eloquent page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)